# Django - First time viewers sometimes are shown a login_required page

Tags: django, authentication

While showing my website to people, I have noticed that sometimes, when viewing the website for the first time, the wrong page is displayed.

```
views.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def index(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
else:
    return render(request, 'free/landing_page.html')


@login_required
def home(request):
...

def login_user(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
    else:
       errors = "True"
       return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'errors': errors})

else:
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

and

```
urls.py


    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name="home"),
```

The idea is to have the home page displayed, if a user already has an account and is authenticated. And if the user is not authenticated then the landing page should be displayed.

So here we go, What I have noticed, is a first time viewer of the website sees the home page rather than the landing page, and to make it even worse, the home page is populated with information from another user's account. From here, if you click on any link you are redirected back to the landing page where you can properly create an account or login. It is strange because the few times this has happened it is on a computer that has never even visited the site before.

I do have `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'` in my settings.py which I am thinking of removing, because of the `return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")` in my user_login function.

**Has anyone ever ran into this before?**

Comment: Do you have any caching enabled?

Comment: As far as I know, I have not enabled any caching. Just using the base Django user authentication right out of the box.